# Javascript keeps modal hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having 2 small issues with some JS below involving a modal and cloning/appending an image:

A button click opens the modal, the modal contains a search bar which populates the content with images. When an image is clicked, it's cloned and appended into another div (outside of modal on the main page) and the modal is closed.

After this is done one time, the button click no longer opens the modal again. How can I alter so that the appending of the images closes the modal but it can be re-opened? 
Also, once the image is appended to a new div, if I click it it disappears. Is there a way to only append the image source without the class tag so that clicking on it in the new div won't make it disappear?

```
    function appendSomeItems(url, id, name, style) {
        return '<div><div class="md-card md-card-hover">         <div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content getImage"> <img class ="uk-align-center imageClick" src="https://media.testsite' + url + '" alt=""></a>                               <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">                                   <span class="gallery_image_title uk-text-truncate">' + name + '</span> <span>' + style + '</span> </div></div></div></div>';
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.imageClick', function handleImage() {
        console.log('good');
        var img = $(this).closest(".getImage").children("img").clone(true);
        $("#holdImage").html('');
        $("#holdImage").append(img);
        $('#image-modal').hide();
    });

   <!--image placeholder->
   <div id="holdImage" style="margin-top: 15px;">                      
   </div>

   <!--open modal-->
   <div style="text-align: center;">
   <a href="#image-modal" data-uk-modal class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Choose an existing image</a>
   </div>

   <!--Modal-->
   <div id="image-modal" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="width:80%;">
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        {!! Form::open(array('id' => 'search_form')) !!}
        <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-1-1">
                <div class="md-card">
                    <div class="md-card-content">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="md-input" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                            <p class="text-center">Search for images by Name </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

        <br/>
        <div id="imageResult" class="gallery_grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-5 uk-grid-width-large-1-6" data-uk-grid="{gutter: 16}">
        </div>
        <button style="display: none;" id="hidden_button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the accompanying HTML and CSS so that we can reproduce your issue and provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Should all be there now, thanks!

Comment: You are using a template engine that handles things like opening the modal so we'll need to have some information on that as well. Removing the class from the image just requires `img.removeClass("ClassToBeRemoved");` before calling `$("#holdImage").append(img);`.

Comment: @SaschaM78 yes I'm using UIKit 2 for the modal, so it has a close button built in and clicking outside of the dialog will close it. I just want the appending of the image to fire the same action, but not hide it for the rest of the page session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem seems to be that you are hiding the entire modal using Jquery's `hide()` message (which will set `display:none;` on the element) rather than calling the modal's `hide()` message. This has also been mentioned on the Git repository as can be seen [here](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/1741).

Solution would be to call the proper `hide` method like so:

```
var modal = UIkit.modal("#image-modal");
modal.hide();
```

instead of

```
$('#image-modal').hide();
```

---

Regarding the other question: remove the class that has the click handler attached before adding it to the `#holdImage` placeholder:

```
var img = $(this).closest(".getImage").children("img").clone(true);
img.removeClass("FillInClassNameHere");
$("#holdImage").html('');
$("#holdImage").append(img);
```

As I don't have the class name for it, you will need to change `FillInClassNameHere` with the proper class name in your code.